# How to push data with multiple types in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to push an array that has strings, numbers and date. Do I have to update individually or is there another way I can accomplish this?

Example:

```
var categories : [String] = self.parseCategories()

var standbyDataStrings = [
    "firstName":firstName,
    "lastName":lastName,
    "categories": categories,
    "time_stamp":self.date.timeIntervalSince1970
]
var standbyDataNums = [
    "radius":nf.numberFromString(self.helpRadiusLabel.text!),
    "duration":nf.numberFromString(self.helpDurationLabel.text!)        
]
standbyUserRef.updateChildValues(standbyDataStrings)
standbyUserRef.updateChildValues(standbyDataNums)  // this gives me a error "string is not identical to NSObject"
```

Combining standByDataStrings and standbyDataNums gives me an error.

Or is there a way to retrieve a string from Firebase and using it as an int. It gets stored as a String with the quotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase API expects an `NSDictionary` for `updateChildValues`. A `NSDictionary` can't contain `nil` values. A normal Swift dictionary on the other hand can contain `nil` values.

The return type of `numberFromString` is `NSNumber?`, so Swift infers that the dictionary might contain `nil` and so it can't be passed to `updateChildValues`. By explicitly forcing non-nil values with `!` you can make this code compile:

```
var standbyDataNums = [ 
    "radius":nf.numberFromString(self.helpRadiusLabel.text!)!,
    "duration":nf.numberFromString(self.helpDurationLabel.text!)!        
]
standbyUserRef.updateChildValues(standbyDataNums) // now type checks
```